# How to get the public key and username from private key using C#?

Tags: cleos

I am trying to implement an C# application. For the simplest, I just want my users to enter their private key only and auto getting their public key and username without any extra input just like Scatter. I know it's possible since scatter and [EOS-Offline-Private-key-check](https://github.com/webdigi/EOS-Offline-Private-key-check) can do it. But I can't find any document or specification of the process. Any ideas or implementation for me? Thanks.

Reference:

https://github.com/webdigi/EOS-Offline-Private-key-check/blob/master/ecc.js#L16861

The reference code is doing the same thing, but due to the complexity for translating JS to C#. I failed to do that with my best effort.

Comment: If you ask nsjames nicely, he'll probably help you out: https://t.me/ScatterDevelopers